# jQuery: Auto scroll to top

Tags: javascript, jquery

i use this script to open a modal:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('.compose').click(function() { 
    $('#popup_bestanden_edit_name').reveal({ 

        animation: 'fade',  
        animationspeed: 600,  
        closeonbackgroundclick: true,  
        dismissModalClass: 'close',
            });
    return false;
});
}); </script>
```

But when i'm at the bottom of the page and click the link, the modal opens at the top of the page.
So it looks like nothing happends, but i have to scroll to the top to see the modal opened.

Is it possible to send the user automatically to the top when the modal is opened?

Comment: Wouldn’t it be a better solution to see to it that the modal opens at the current document position, instead of forcing the page to scroll up so that the user has to go back to the position they were at before afterwards …?

Comment: Yes, you are right. But i don't know how to fix that exactly. But that would be an option too.

Comment: Problem fixed! See: 

Just added the CSS here: http://jsfiddle.net/mondico/et47L/1/

I changed the position: absolute to fixed. That did the job!

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `position: fixed` and for example `top: 30px` to styles for `#popup_bestanden_edit_name`. If you do that, modal will appear always in the same place, no matter where the user is on the page. But then you must be careful, because if modal is higher than viewport, you won't be able to see the remaining part of modal.

If you still want to scroll to top (without animation), using JavaScript you can put

```
$('body').scrollTop(0);
```

right before your `return false;`

BTW, if you want to prevent default action of a link to fire, it's a better practice to do it that way:

```
$('.compose').click(function(event) {
    // your code here
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: I know, but thats the problem.
The modal is fixed already on the top, but thats not what i want.
Cause' when i'm at the bottom of the page and i open the modal, it opens at the top and i can't see it, unless i scroll to the top of the page.

Comment: You're confusing `position: fixed` with `position: absolute`.

Answer (score 11):

use below code to move to top of page:

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '0px'}, 0);
```

Instead of 0, you can have some other value like 500 (its in milliseconds) to make it move to top slowly

Comment: Thank u,

i tried that one, but i'm not sure where to put it, or how, see my example:

http://jsfiddle.net/mondico/et47L/

It's not complete, but i't shows how i put it in the jQuery..
But i don't understand how to do it..

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not to scroll to the top of the page. It is not good UX Design! We can have overflow hidden on the body. So, user can not scroll once popup comes to screen. We need to give position fixed to the main element of the popup.

I would suggest to check below snippet.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .nooverflow {overflow: hidden;}
            .popup {position: fixed; z-index: 99;}
            .cover {position: fixed; background: #000; opacity: .5; filter: alpha(opacity=50); top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 1000; }
            .popup-conteiner {overflow-y: auto; position: fixed; height: 100%; width: 100%; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 101;}
            .popup-block {position: relative; top: 100px; z-index: 101;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="popup">
            <div class="cover"></div>
            <div class="popup-conteiner">
                <div class="popup-block">
                    <!-- POPUP's HTML GOES HERE -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But, if it does not work then you can scroll page to the top of the page. You can use solution given by Rajesh as well. I would like to add a condition that if page is already animated then stop before doing new animation.

```
var htmlBody = $("html,body"),
    top = 0;

if (htmlBody.is(':animated')) {
    htmlBody.stop(true, true);  //Need to stop if it is already being animated
}

htmlBody.animate({ scrollTop: top }, 1000); //Scroll to the top of the page by animating for 1 sec.
```

Comment: Thank u, i now solved the problem by setting the CSS to FIXED in stead of ABSOLUTE.

That makes the popup opens on the document location the user is at that moment.

Comment: I am glad that you found the solution. I also like animate method to scroll to given top as well. Make sure to Stop (http://api.jquery.com/stop/) or Dequeue (http://api.jquery.com/dequeue/) animation to avoid buggy effects.

Comment: I worked around Chrome by using scrollIntoView on the DOM node, for an item at the top of the container you want to scroll to the top of, like header, say.